# Isotope filtering not working on anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope, lightgallery

I'm creating a portfolio site to showcase my works. I'm using Light Gallery to display images and videos on my website. I wanted to add the Filtering option by using the Isotope.js

I'm not able to figure out what is wrong with my code.
I've setup a pen on [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/kannan3024/pen/QdKGyB)

Please feel free to add up to the code.

```
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.nlg1').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.revGallery-anchor',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
// filter functions
var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match( /ium$/ );
  }
};
// bind filter button click
$('.filters-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser console. `$lg is not defined` - seems to work fine if you remove whatever that code is. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apmBEd

Comment: Hi Micheal,
I've made those change in codepen as well as my project. But its not working in my project. Anything else should be added. Someone in the forum told me about imageloaded.js. should i use it

Comment: @Kamalakannan the filtering is working when I go to it in codepen. You're saying it doesn't work in the codepen? What happens?

Comment: @Kamalakannan ok... not sure what to tell you since I can't see your code.

Comment: Ok.. I'll host a preview and link it. Please help me.

Comment: hey Micheal. I figured it. It was placement of the code. I had to place this code at the end. It worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: BTW there's another thing, I'll ask that in the question. please try to answer.

Comment: Please Answer this as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672117/isotope-filters-to-only-display-filtered-light-gallery-images