# Isotope Filters to only display Filtered Light Gallery images

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope, lightgallery

I wanted to create a filtering portfolio for my website, I've got everything setup but the thing is, When I use Isotope to filter a category, of course it filters out but when I click on the image and fire up lightgallery, it shows all the images from all categories.

I want the images of a particular category to be visible in the slideshow of lightgallery.
I saw some answer in stack, I guess I need to implement a shadowbox. but don't know how.

Please help me.

My [Codepen](http://codepen.io/kannan3024/pen/YWoQgq)

```
//isotope Code
$('#gallery').isotope({
   // options
   itemSelector: '.revGallery-anchor',
   layoutmode: 'fitrows'
});
$('button').on( 'click', function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$('#gallery').isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a closure when you initialize lightGallery, you can use the API to destroy the current instance and re-initialize when you click the isotope filter buttons.

Create a closure and initialize lightGallery

```
$gallery = $('#gallery'); 

$gallery.lightGallery({...});
```

And when you click on the isotope filter button, destroy that instance and re-initialize based on the class of the elements you want to be in the gallery. That class is `filterValue` here

```
$gallery.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);

$gallery.lightGallery({
  selector: filterValue.replace('*','');
});
```

http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/KaWKvE

Comment: You are awesome, you've done it again. But the "ALL" category is not working, I guess its because it has a star ( * ) for data-filter. Please see what can be done.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. Its Working Perfectly.

Comment: @Kamalakannan sweet, np :)

Comment: Hi Micheal, May I ask you to answer this. Please.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810492/preloader-before-lightgallery-isotope-using-imageloaded